# Distinct count for two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I've been looking around and can't find an answer to this question on finding a distinct match. I have a table that looks like

```
ID       Category      Relevancy
192820   273003000  2
242567   273003000  2
510711   273003000  2
510711   273003002  34
542178   273003000  1
551356   273003002  1
688833   273003000  3
734917   273003002  2
888879   273003000  1
891624   273003002  3
```

So for each id they can have multiple categories and the relevancy is what what category number (1 is the first category, 2 second, 34 the thirty fourth category for that id).

I want to query where I can search the count of the Category but if the id has already been counted for a category it will not be counted.

So for this the answer would look like:

```
Category         Count  
273003000         6
273003002         2
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you exclude an ID from a Category if that ID is related to a category with an earlier ID, the following will work. It is not exactly clear from your questions how the exclusion works. If you can clarify that, the query can be adjusted

```
SELECT  t1.category
        ,count(distinct t1.ID)
FROM    table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT 1
        FROM    table1 t2 
        WHERE   t2.id = t1.id 
        AND t2.category < t1.category
        )
GROUP BY
        t1.category
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10180/5)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `GROUP BY` like this:-

```
select Category, COUNT(*) as Count
from YourTable
GROUP BY Category;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2354c/2)